# Remote access to 20.04 locks window manager after a few minutes being idle

Tags: linux-kvm, xfce4, ubuntu-20.04, x2go

I have a ubunutu 20.04 VM running on a KVM server.  The KVM server is on an updated ubuntu 20.04 system.  The VM is basically an unmodified version that was just downloaded and updated.  Added x2go so I can access it from a windows machine.  Using the latest x2go version that works just fine on the 16 and 18 versions of ubuntu VMs running on the same KVM server.  The window manager I'm running is xfce.  The only weird thing I have here is btrfs configured on a second disk (but not being accessed).  The root volume is the default ext4 file system as configured during install.

I can connect to the VM via x2go, run a few terminals, commands, etc.  Everything seems to run as it should.  However, if I leave it alone for a few minutes (I haven't timed it yet but less than 30) it appears that the window manager has hung.  Well, sort of.  The keyboard has no effect.  Clicking the mouse also has no effect.  Moving the mouse over the corner of a terminal window will change the mouse image to the one to allow resizing, but the resizing won't work.  I have to reboot the VM to clear this.

I attempted to run a background script in one of the windows that outputs the date every 30 seconds.  That will keep running and scrolling the window even after this failure event.  The console brought up on the KVM server directly from the virtual machine manager does not exhibit this behavior.

Tried running x2go on Windows 7 as well as an updated Windows 10 machine with the same results.

I played around with the sshd timeout values with no effect, which is what I expected if the output of the date script above still generated output.

Note that an x2go connection directly to the 20.04 KVM server (not one of the VMs) also exhibits this same behavior.

Interestingly, I also setup a fresh 20.04 VM on a qNAP server.  It has a way to bring up a console within a web page for a VM.  This also exhibited this same behavior.

As I said, the 16 and 18 versions of ubuntu work fine on the same infrastructure.

Everything seems to point at something with 20.04 but I have a hard time believing the rest of the world would put up with this kind of behavior.  No idea what in my environment would cause something like this.

Not sure where else to look.  Any ideas?  I'd rather not go back to 18.04 but will as needed.  This makes it impossible for me to use 20.04.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to user300458 at this link

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1217935/ubuntu-studio-20-04-freezes-everything-but-mouse-after-lid-closes-and-opens#

it appears that it is a power management issue.  I had to go to system settings, power, go to the display tab, then turn the "switch" widget off.  This fixed the x2go and qNAP console issues.